# Ajax callback issue

Tags: 8, ajax

[image]

I am using ajax callback on field_status. This is a drop down menu. A selection in field_status should trigger comment fill-up. I am getting blank comment box.

```
function helper_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
    {
        /**
          *
          */
        if($form_id == 'comment_comment_form')
        {
             if(isset($form['field_status_']))
             {
                 $form['field_status_']['widget'][0]['#default_value']['#ajax'] = array(
                                             'callback' => 'statusDescriptionCallBack',
                                             'event' => 'change',
                                              );
             }
        }
    }
function statusDescriptionCallBack(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
   $my_comment_status_selection = $form_state ->getValue('field_status_')[0]['target_id'];
   \Drupal::logger($my_comment_status_selection);
   if($my_comment_status_selection == 11)
   {
       $form['comment_body']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] = "This is fade";
   }

   return $form['comment_body']['widget'][0]['#default_value'];

}
```

Comment: Is the Status field a reference field type or list field type? Are you sure the machine name of the field `field_status_` ending with an `_` ? Check in `/admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/fields`.

Comment: Also, attaching the *#ajax* definition to the *#default_value* property doesn't make sense. The default value doesn't change with user interaction.

Comment: Yes, the machine name is correct. The fields in field_status_ are of reference field types(taxonomy term).